# jTable function getSelectedRow(), getSelectedColumn() returning -1

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am new in Java programming. I need to get the indices of selected column and row. I am getting -1 as selected indices for both the column and row. I have searched for a solution but didn't find anything satisfactory.

My code is following:

```
private void deleteProductButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) this.productDisplaTable.getModel();
    JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

    int selectedRowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
    int selectedColIndex = table.getSelectedColumn();
    System.out.println(selectedRowIndex );
    System.out.println(selectedColIndex);
}
```

Comment: you haven't select anything

Comment: -1 means no row selected. Are you sure you're selecting a row? Click on a row and try again.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your reply. I have selected one, multiple rows, columns but it still returning -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you create a new JTable but you don't add this component to any container. Thus it won't never be visible and no row nor column could ever be selected.

Now, while we can add components dynamically in Swing we tipically place all our components before the top-level container (window) is made visible. In this case you should place the table when you initialize your components (don't forget the scroll pane) and do whatever you need to do when the button is pressed.

On the other hand I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. I mean you already have a table called `productDisplaTable`. If you want to print the selected row and column in that table then make this little change:

```
private void deleteProductButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    //DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) this.productDisplaTable.getModel();
    //JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);    
    int selectedRowIndex = this.productDisplaTable.getSelectedRow();
    int selectedColIndex = this.productDisplaTable.getSelectedColumn();
    System.out.println(selectedRowIndex );
    System.out.println(selectedColIndex);
}
```

Comment: Hi
I got confused with TableModel, JTable instances. The line "JTable table = new JTable(tableModel); " i took from internet blindly just to try out whether it works or not.

Actually, your code solves the problem. 
Thanks a ton.

Comment: You are welcome @user3509781 that's the risk of blindly copy code from internet: You don't understand what are you doing. If you are a beginner then I'd suggest you to start reading Swing tutorials. There are complete working examples to help you to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 3):

You're checking if a row is selected before the JTable has been displayed before the user can even interact with it.

Instead why not have that code in an ActionListener or some other listener so that the user at least has a chance to select something? This suggests that you might have a misunderstanding on how event-driven programming works and need to study the concepts a little bit more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually I am pressing the delete button in a page where the table exists already and the user get to select an element. After that he presses the button. I am indeed confused with event-driven programming.

Answer (score 3):

What makes you think that creating a a new `JTable` would have any selected rows or columns

```
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel); //???
```

Try using a table that is actually visible to the user instead

Comment: This is where I am confused. 
In the UI, there is a table, user selects a cell then press the deleteButton. The code I have given is the deleteButtonActionPerformed. 

I need to obtain the row index and column index that user selected. Could you please tell me what I need to do just to get these indices?

Comment: @user3509781 So why are you creating a new instance of `JTable` passing it the `tableModel` from the instance of `productDisplaTable`?  The `TableModel` models the data, not the state of the UI

Comment: Got the answer I was looking from @dic19's comment (given below).
Thanks for taking time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for taking time to reply. 
I got the answer I was looking from @dic19's comment.
Now I clearly see the mistake I was doing. This was due to my lack of knowledge in Java programming.